# How to set BootStrap Navbar on page right dropdown width only occupy necessary space？

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

Please look at the image below, i have a navbar toggle button on the upper right conner of page,
when i expand it, the actual width of the dropdown items occupies the entire page width, this causes a problem that if you move your mouse to any point within the red box(even not on the `change bg` text), you can still trigger the dropdown link action.

How can i limit the dropdown item effective area only on the text itself? (and i don't want the text come to the left side of page)
Thanks for your help.

[image]

Here is the code i am using:

```
<nav class="navbar  navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../../assets/images/yet.png" alt="" srcset=""></a>
        <ul *ngIf="!name" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li  class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="login">login</a>
            </li>
            <!-- <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="signup">Signup</a>
            </li> -->
          </ul>


        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
                data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

              <li *ngIf="name" class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">{{name}}</a>
                </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link drop" href="#" (click)="switchBackground()">change bg</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">settings</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" (click)="logoff()">Log Off</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the below css to your component

```
.nav-link{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The links are `block` by default. So they would take the complete width. Change them to `inline-block`.

For moving the menu items to the left, apply the below css

```
.navbar-nav{
    text-align: left;
}
```

The text should be aligned left by default. Maybe you have some other CSS in body which is overriding the default behaviour.

Comment: `display: inline-block` works like a charm. and you are right about the text alignment, i am using `text-align: right` on dropdown items.